# ; in cookie value trims cookie in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am saving a cookie using a value from a database and then accessing that cookie on another page.  i noticed that if the cookie has a ; in it's value, it is cut off at that ;.  How do I fix this other than changing the data so it does not include ;?

Answer (score 1):

That is a limitation of http. You will have to encode the cookie value like this

```
string cookieValue = Server.UrlEncode(someValue);
```

and decoding is

```
string someValue = Server.UrlDecode(cookieValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Semi-colons are special characters when it comes to cookies. You'll have to encode its value in the cookie somehow.

Since you're using ASP.NET, it should be as easy as calling:

```
cookieString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cookieString);
```